# Extending Doctrine_Query

Tags: symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I wantend to create a complex grouping using doctrine query and I used Snippets:

[Snippet Doctrine custom grouping](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/371)

```php
$q = myDQ::create()
  ->from('Some s');
```

It gives me a mistake:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of MyDq::create() shuld be compatible with that of Doctrine_Query::create() in URL-ROOT/lib/MyDq.class.php

Comment: Could you show us the whole query you want to create ? Not only the create & from ?

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine_Query:create is declared this way:

```
public static function create($conn = null, $class = null)
```

you did:

```
public static function create($conn = null)
```

which doesn't work because of the different arguments.

For information on overriding static methods you may also find this page interesting: [php.net/manual/language.oop5.static.php](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.static.php)